# HBase update and delete

Tags: hbase

I have HBase table as

UserId UserName UserScore

1 a 100
2 b 200

We have a web app which get data by UserId and update the score and store it again in HBase.
The problem here in HBase is if we update the row in HBase table it add the row with new version.
How can i write the update code and how can i maintain only one row for each userid with out the versions.

Answer (score 0):

The other option is to delete the old value and put the new value back in the cell. and if you do not want multiple versions, set the VERSION=>1 while creating the table. for instance, create one row corresponding to each userID and set VERSION=>1. as you get new data for a user go to the corresponding, row delete the older value and put the new value there.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to HBase world and came across same problem. But it looks like that setting the timestamp same and the calling put method should solve update issue. It wont add new version.